# How to list all continents with the countries gem?

Tags: ruby, countries

Using the Countries gem https://github.com/hexorx/countries

We have the method:

`ISO3166::Country.find_all_countries_by_continent('Europe')`

We also have:
`ISO3166::Country.countries`

But we don't have:
`ISO3166::Country.continents`

I want to have a 'Filter by continent' `select` which could be translated using I18n.

Is there an easy way to get all available continents?

Comment: You could easily use the countries to collect the distinct continent names. But truly this seems like sort of a flaw in the architecture to me. If this were a database, there would be a continents table and a country would have a key into it; just writing the continent name as _text_ for every country individually is insanely fragile.

Comment: The list of countries changes regularly. I cannot remember the last time the list of continents changed. Presumably, the author of the gem didn't think someone would need to query a dynamic list of continents. I believe it would reasonably safe to not make the list of continents dynamic; I don't think you will be forced to upgrade your software too often.

Answer (score 0):

As I know (I can be wrong), I think hexorx/countries not give you this possibility natively.

**Ps :**
I have created an [feature request](https://github.com/hexorx/countries/issues/668) for this if it can make things happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the continents using

```
ISO3166::Data.cache.map {|_,v| v['continent']}.uniq
#=> ["Asia", "North America", "Africa", "Europe", "South America", "Antarctica", "Australia"]
```

Due to the fact that this list is highly unlikely to change in the foreseeable future you can just cache these results for your self

```
ISO3166::CONTINENTS = ISO3166::Data.cache.map {|_,v| v['continent']}.uniq.sort
```

Then you can just reuse the constant `ISO3166::CONTINENTS` anywhere you need to.

That being said the `i18n_data` gem (that is used for translation of countries) does not appear to provide translation for continent names so that would likely fall on your shoulders to maintain.

A `Set` might make this slightly more efficient too: (although since getting the continents is simply `Array` traversal and `Hash` lookup it is already reasonably fast)

```
ISO3166::CONTINENTS = ISO3166::Data.cache.each_with_object(Set.new)  do |(_,v),s| 
  s.add(v['continent'])
end.sort
```